# Grouping expand and collapse in GWT

Tags: gwt, uibinder, gwt2

I have multiple records which needs to be displayed as part of a search. A single result can contain multiple records associated to it. If there are multiple records I need to display the record with (+)  and when clicked it further displays the list.

- I would like to know what the best way is to implement ( I have checked Custom data grid ex: http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCustomDataGrid but would like to use UI binder)
- Once the user selects a record from the expanded list, how can we load that selected record?

Any pointer are appreciated..! ( Currently on GWT 2.2)

Comment: Custom DataGrid uses features that are not available on 2.2. I think for this you need 2.5.1

Answer (score 0):

[Widget list](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefWidgetGallery.html)

`Tree` or maybe `StackPanel` seems like it would be useful here.